# Is there a __equals method in PHP like there is in Java?

Tags: php, oop, equals

Is there a pattern or magic method you can use in PHP to define when to compare two instances of a class?

For example, in Java I could easily override the `equals` method and create a custom way of checking and compare two instances.

Comment: Do you wish to compare objects that are the same instance or two object instances from the same class? Did you check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)?

Comment: Java has no magic methods so I don’t know what exactly you’re asking. Sure, you can just add methods like you can in Java.

Comment: Rather than comparing `$ClassA === $ClassB`, just implement equals yourself, so you can do `$ClassA->equals($ClassB)`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In a word? No. There is no `__equals` magic method. There is a complete list of the magic methods [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

You can do

```
$myObject1 == $myObject2
```

which will consider them equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.

I have often wished for this type of method myself, but I think that a more useful one would be a `__compare()` method which would be called for any comparison operator <, >, ==, ===, etc it already exist for PHP's inbuilt classes as can be seen in the [PHP internals wiki](https://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects) and there is an example of how it could be implemented in the [PHPInternals book](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/magic_interfaces_comparable.html):-

> compare_objects
>
> ```
> int (*compare)(zval *object1, zval *object2 TSRMLS_DC)
> ```
>
> Compares two objects. Used for the operators ==, !=, <, >, ⇐ and >=.
>   The implementations should follow these rules – for any objects a, b and c that share the same compare handler:

One way I have used to achieve this is to implement a Comparable interface, something like:-

```
interface Comparable
{
    /**
     * @param Comparable $other
     * 
     * @return Int -1, 0 or 1 Depending on result of comparison
     */
    public function compareTo(Comparable $other);
}
```

The details of object comparison, and everything else OOP related can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php.

<strike>[This may be implemented in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/comparable).</strike>

There is now an implementation of this that you can install using composer. https://github.com/Fleshgrinder/php-comparable

Comment: The second argument is not correct since a comparison should return -1 (smaller), 0 (equal), or 1 (larger).

Comment: @Fleshgrinder I'm not sure that would work in PHP as it currently stands. Although I am always open to learning something new :O)

Comment: Check out any compare method in C, Java, ... as well as any of the compare functions and methods in PHP itself. They always return one of those numbers. The `usort` callback is also required to return one of those numbers. See my added answer in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly not, but you can quite easily replicate something close. For example:-

```
<?php
interface IComparable {
    public function compare(self $subject);
}

class Foo implements IComparable {
    public function compare(self $subject) {
        return $this->__toString() === $subject->__toString();
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return serialize($this);
    }
}

function compare(IComparable $a, IComparable $b) {
    return $a->compare($b);
}

$a = new Foo;
$b = new Foo;

var_dump(compare($a, $b)); //true

$a->name = 'A';
$b->name = 'B';

var_dump(compare($a, $b)); //false
```

It's not particularly elegant, but should get you on your way.

Anthony.

Comment: This will actually end up in a fatal error due to the usage of `self` which points to `IComparable` in the interface and `Foo` in `Foo` and thus the implementation does not fulfill the contract.

Answer (score 4):

First off the `==` operator is sufficient in most cases, especially if we are talking about value objects. Just be sure to provide a `__toString` method if you want the ability to compare the instance with scalar values.

```
<?php

final class ValueObject {

    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }

}

$a = new ValueObject(0);
$b = new ValueObject(1);

var_dump(
    $a == $b,  // bool(false)
    $a == $a,  // bool(true)
    $b == $b,  // bool(true)
    $a == '0', // bool(true)
    $b == '1'  // bool(true)
);
```

There is one gotcha with this, you cannot compare to scalar type other than string (at least not in PHP 5 and 7) because it will complain that the instance could not be converted to the desired value. Hence, you always need to ensure that the value type you compare to is a string.

If you want more than that, e.g. you want to lowercase the input or handle float value up until a certain accuracy, you need a different approach. One way to handle this is as follows.

```
<?php

interface Comparable {

    function compareTo(Comparable $other): int;

}

function class_compare(Comparable $a, Comparable $b): int {
    return $a->compareTo($b);
}

final class C implements Comparable {

    private $value;

    public function __construct(int $value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function compareTo(Comparable $other): int {
        assert($this instanceof $other && $other instanceof $this);

        return $this->value <=> $other->value;
    }

}

$c1 = new C(0);
$c2 = new C(0);

var_dump($c1->compareTo($c2)); // int(0)

$c0 = new C(0);
$c1 = new C(1);
$c2 = new C(2);

$actual = [$c2, $c1, $c0];
usort($actual, 'class_compare');

var_dump($actual === [$c0, $c1, $c2]); // bool(true)
```

The `assert` is important since we have no generics in PHP. This is a pretty sad state of things and there is no pretty way to implement this.

What I tend to do is the following.

```
<?php

final class SomeClass {

    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public static function compare(SomeClass $a, SomeClass $b): int {
        return $a->compareTo($b);
    }

    public function compareTo(SomeClass $other): int {
        return $this->value <=> $other->value;
    }

    public function isEqual($other): bool {
        return $other instanceof $this && $other->value === $this->value;
    }

    public function isIdentical($other): bool {
        return $other instanceof $this && $this instanceof $other && $other->value === $this->value;
    }

}
```

Simply sticking to these method names by convention allows it to use them appropriately. One could even provide traits to implement the desired default behavior among multiple classes.

Comment: Is it necessary to assert both `$this instanceof $other` and `$other instanceof $this`? Any hints on when these two comparisons would yield different result?

Comment: Not necessary, it depends on what you want. `$other instanceof $this` means that `$other` is either `$this` or a subclass of `$this`. The next check disallows sublcasses, since `$this` must be an instance of `$other` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, as everyone says, this will do:

```
$object1 == $object2
```

Compares type and properties.

---

But what I do in this cases, when I want to personalize my equality methods, is implement the magic method __toString() in the classes I want to assert equality.

```
class Car {
  private $name;
  private $model;
   ...
  public function __toString() {
     return $this->name.", ".$this->model;
  }
}
```

And then when I want to do the comparision I just do this:

```
$car1->toString() === $car2->toString()
```

And that will compare if the two instances have the same attributes.

The other option (as halfer states in the comments) is implement an equal method that asserts equality of another instance of the same class. For example:

```
class Car {
  private $name;
  private $model;
   ...
  public function equals(Car $anotherCar) {
         if($anotherCar->getName() !== $this->name) {
           return false;
         }

         if($anotherCar->getModel() !== $this->model) {
           return false;
         }
         ...
         return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare your custom object, you can do it like this:

```
$time1 = new MyTimeClass("09:35:12");
$time2 = new MyTimeClass("09:36:09");

if($time1 > $time2) echo "Time1 is bigger";
else echo "Time2 is bigger";

//result: Time2 is bigger
```

It compares the first property found in the class, in my case an int value that holds the total number of seconds in the given time.
If you put the $seconds property on top you'll notice that it gives an unexpected 'Time1 is bigger'.

```
class MyTimeClass {
    public $intValue;
    public $hours;
    public $minutes;
    public $seconds;

    public function __construct($str){
        $array = explode(":",$str);
        $this->hours = $array[0];
        $this->minutes = $array[1];
        $this->seconds = $array[2];
        $this->intValue = ($this->hours * 3600) + ($this->minutes * 60) + $this->seconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually [**first unequal property**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41590431/3705191), so it will compare every property till the first one that's not the same in the two objects. Thanks a lot, btw, for this hidden piece of info, exactly what I needed! :)