# Objects comparison in PHP

Tags: php, object, comparison

SO,

**The problem**

It's not well-known, but PHP allows to compare objects - and not just on equality `==` - but on `<` and `>` too. But - how it works? So if I want to create comparable objects - what restrictions/rules they should follow?

Most useful case is with [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/DateTime) objects - they hold certain timestamp and they could be compared (and this has logical sense). On [lxr](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/date/php_date.c#2017) there's some explanation for `DateTime` . But what about common case?

I have:

```
class C
{
   protected $holder;
   protected $mirror;
   public function __construct($h = null)
   {
      $this->holder=$h;
      $this->mirror=-1*$h;
   }
}


$one = new C(1);
$two = new C(2);
//false, false, true: used $holder
var_dump($one>$two, $one==$two, $one<$two);
```

-if I'll change properties **declaration** order, it will use `$mirror`:

```
class C
{
   //only order changed:
   protected $mirror;
   protected $holder;
   public function __construct($h = null)
   {
      $this->holder=$h;
      $this->mirror=-1*$h;
   }
}

$one = new C(1);
$two = new C(2);
//true, false, false: used $mirror
var_dump($one>$two, $one==$two, $one<$two);
```

So it seems one of the 'rules' is that it will use first declared property. But why is it using `protected` property at all is not clear to me too.

Now, more complex sample:

```
class Test
{
  protected $a;
  protected $b;

  function __construct($a, $b)
  {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;
  }
}

$x = new Test(1, 2);
$y = new Test(1, 3);

// true, false, false
var_dump($x < $y, $x == $y, $x > $y);

$x = new Test(3, 1);
$y = new Test(2, 1);

// false, false, true
var_dump($x < $y, $x == $y, $x > $y);
```

-so it will use *first not-equal* property for comparison. But code snippets above are only some cases. I want to know exactly how it's happening and why. Thus,

**Question**

Is: **how it works**? I mean, more detailed:

- Can I rely on fact, that PHP will use first not-equal property for comparison?
- What will be done if count of properties isn't equal? (i.e. some property was dynamically added to instance during code execution)
- Can I treat `protected`/`private` properties as to be counted for such comparison always?

e.t.c. - so if there are some additional conditions/restrictions/rules that will affect result - please, post. [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) states only for `==`/`===` comparison. Also, comparison of instances of different classes is out of the issue since it'll return `false` (obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP compares sequentially (in the order of declaration) the object properties and stops at the first inequal property found. This behavior is not documented, so there's not much to be said about it, sadly, other than looking at the source of PHP.

Not documented is usually a synonym of "don't rely on it".

Comment: Good. If it's not documented, then how do you know that it will be done such way? My current thought is the same - but I want to know if I can rely on this. But searching through lxr, for example, wasn' helpful. Thus, I want some proof for - such behavior is as it is intended to work

Comment: If you *really* want to see how it works, [this is the comparison function](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_operators.c#1593). It's not commented, but basically: if a comparison handler is defined for the object, it will call it (such as for `DateTime`).

Answer (score 2):

Each class in php has an associated structure (in the c code) of handler functions, it looks like

```
struct _zend_object_handlers {
    /* general object functions */
    zend_object_add_ref_t                   add_ref;
    zend_object_del_ref_t                   del_ref;
[...]
    zend_object_compare_t                   compare_objects;
[...]
};
```

`compare_objects` points to a function that "takes two objects" and returns -1,0,1 according to whatever this comparator defines as the order (just like strcmp() does for strings).
This function is used only when both operands (objects) point to the same comparision function - but let's just stick with this case.
That's where e.g. `DateTime` "adds" its feature to compare two DateTime instances, it just defines another, DateTime-specific `compare_objects` function and puts it in the structure describing its class.

```
static void date_register_classes(TSRMLS_D)
{
[...]

    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce_date, "DateTime", date_funcs_date);
    ce_date.create_object = date_object_new_date;
[...]
    date_object_handlers_date.compare_objects = date_object_compare_date;
```

So if you want to know (exactly) how two DateTime instances are compared, take a look at [`date_object_compare_date`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/date/php_date.c;h=f6b12bc42ed9b69ade1dd18c26c7bb42b664ead1;hb=3156580a34b947e4325fdd165015904153790c39#l2165).

The [comparision described in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) (at least for the case cmp(o1,o2)==0) seems to be implemented in [`zend_std_compare_objects`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=Zend/zend_object_handlers.c;h=093951eecafc6fe183131f8d6057e1e88e690f47;hb=3156580a34b947e4325fdd165015904153790c39#l1342). And it's used by both StdClass and a simple user defined class like e.g.

```
<?php
class Foo { }
$a = new StdClass;
$b = new Foo;

$a > $b;
```

But other classes (in php extensions) do set other functions. DateTime, ArrayObject, PDOStatement, even Closures use different functions.
But I haven't found a way to define a comparision function/method in script code (but haven't looked too hard/long)

Comment: Nice explanation with `DateTime` - indeed, I've looked into internal implementation (so it's as you've posted)

Answer (score 1):

The exact behavior is defined in the [PHP language specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#relational-operators), thus, you can rely on it.

> […] if the objects are of different types, the comparison result is FALSE. If the objects are of the same type, the properties of the objects are compares *[sic]* using the array comparison described above.

And the array comparison is defined as follows:

> […] For arrays having the same numbers of elements, the keys from the left operand are considered one by one, if the next key in the left-hand operand exists in the right-hand operand, the corresponding values are compared. If they are unequal, the array containing the lesser value is considered less-than the other one, and the comparison ends; otherwise, the process is repeated with the next element. […] If all the values are equal, then the arrays are considered equal.

Simply exchange every mention of *array* with *object* and *key* with *property* in your mind and you have the exact description of how this works. I omitted useless array specifics in above quote.