# PHP object comparison and private properties

Tags: php

I am wondering how PHP determines the equality of instances of a class with private properties:

```
class Example {
    private $x;
    public $y;
    public __construct($x,$y) {
        $this->x = $x; $this->y = $y;
    }
}
```

and something like

```
$needle = new Example(1,2);
$haystack = [new Example(2,2), new Example(1,2)];
$index = array_search($needle, $haystack); //  result is 1
```

The result is indeed 1, so the private member is compared. **Is there a possibility to only match public properties?**

I know I could overwrite the `__toString` method and cast all arrays and needles to string, but that leads to ugly code.

I am hoping to find a solution that is elegant enough to work with `in_array`, `array_search`, `array_unique`, etc.

Comment: _“Is there a possibility to only match public properties?”_ - no, that is not possible. (And I don’t know how much sense it would make in the first place. Both elements need to be of the same class to begin with here - and then “private” doesn’t even matter on that level. If `$a` and `$b` are of the same class, then `$a` _has_ access to the private properties of `$b` anyway.)

Comment: I read that `array_unique` does cast to string automatically before comparison. I am searching for a consistent `array_search` routine.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528491/476

Comment: That you will probably have to write yourself then.

Comment: It's a pity that different library methods behave differently. A behavior like `array_unique` would have been great. Maybe PHP 9 will have support for a `__compare` feature.

Comment: If we follow your example strictly, they are still one and the same class definition. It 's like @CBroe said before. It makes no sense to compare the same class definitions this way. The class `Example` contains one private member. It will be this specific private member in any instance. There will be no difference between instances as long as the are of the type `Example`.

Comment: Yes, in the end I was looking for a `__compare` feature. I initially read this official article https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php and was wondering if "they have the same attributes and values" also includes private attributes. The answer is simply "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the PHP Reflection API. With that in mind you can read the public properties of a class and compare them to other public properties of another instance of the same class.

The following code is a simple comparison of public class properties. The base for the comparison is a simple value object.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Test;

use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionProperty;

class Example
{
    private string $propertyA;
    public string $propertyB;
    public string $propertyC;

    public function getPropertyA(): string
    {
        return $this->propertyA;
    }

    public function setPropertyA(string $propertyA): self
    {
        $this->propertyA = $propertyA;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPropertyB(): string
    {
        return $this->propertyB;
    }

    public function setPropertyB($propertyB): self
    {
        $this->propertyB = $propertyB;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPropertyC(): string
    {
        return $this->propertyC;
    }

    public function setPropertyC($propertyC): self
    {
        $this->propertyC = $propertyC;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __compare(Example $b, $filter = ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC): bool
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($b);
        $properties = $reflection->getProperties($filter);
    
        $same = true;
    
        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            if (!property_exists($this, $property->getName())) {
                $same = false;
            }
        
            if ($this->{$property->getName()} !== $property->getValue($b)) {
                $same = false;
            }
        }
    
        return $same;
    }
}
```

The `__compare` method of the `Example` class uses the [PHP Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). First we build a reflection instance of the class to which we want to compare to the current instance. Then we request all public properties of the class we want to compare to. If a public property does not exist in the instance or the value of the property is not the same as in the object we want to compare to, the method returns false, otherwise true.

Some examples.

```
$objectA = (new Example())
    ->setPropertyA('bla')
    ->setPropertyB('yadda')
    ->setPropertyC('bar');

$objectB = (new Example())
    ->setPropertyA('foo')
    ->setPropertyB('yadda')
    ->setPropertyC('bar');

$result = $objectA->__compare($objectB);
var_dump($result); // true
```

In this example the comparison results into `true` because the public properties `PropertyB` and `PropertyC` exist in both instances and have the same values. Keep in mind, that this comparison works only, if the second instance is the same class. One could spin this solution further and compare all possible objects based on their characteristics.

### In Array Filter Example

It is a kind of rebuild of the `in_array` function based on the shown `__compare` method.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Test;

class InArrayFilter 
{
    protected ArrayObject $data;

    public function __construct(ArrayObject $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function contains(object $b)
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $object) {
            if ($b->__compare($object)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    }
}
```

This filter class acts like the `in_array` function. It takes a collection of objects and checks, if an object with the same public properties is in the collection.

### Conclusion

If you want this solution to act like `array_unique`, `array_search` or `ìn_array` you have to code your own callback functions which execute the `__compare` method in the way you want to get the result.

It depends on the amount of data to be handled and the performance of the callback methods. The application could consume much more memory and therefore become slower.