# How do you build persistent object identity in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the next issue:

I'm trying to form up an identity of an array of objects that I save. This identy, I will, upon generation of these objects, check again and see if it's identical or different from the newly resulted idenity of the new generation -- if it is, update my database with this identity (which should be a unique string), otherwise, I don't do anything. The code is as follows:

```
class GoodSuggestion {}
class BadSuggestion {}
class MiscSuggestion {}

$container_items = [new GoodSuggestion, new BadSuggestion, new MiscSuggestion];

$identity = createIdentityFromObjects( $container_items );

//If my identity from NOW doesn't match the past identity, it means we have a new object inside
if( $identity != retrievePastIdentityFromDatabase() ) {

    //And so, we re-generate the suggestions
    $generated_suggestions = $generator->generateSuggestion( $container_items );

    //and update the database with the new identity so that in the future, before we generate, we can check again.
    updateIdentityInTheDatabase( $identity );
}
```

How can I reliably build identity for an object, given my requirements?

I will have cases where an object is of the same `Base_Object`, so I need to compute the data inside too.

I do acknowledge the limitation of not being able to compute differences between implementation details (such as a single character being added to the same, otherwise identical class). This needs to compute an indentity string based on reasonable terms.

Comment: Not sure to understand the question and what you mean by "face", but maybe a hash of a serialization?

Comment: @Blackhole Edited. Sorry, I had something in my mnid and it didn't come out right.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008622/is-there-a-equals-method-in-php-like-there-is-in-java

Comment: @Thomas It seems it's related, but I'm testing right now.